# Admob Rewarded Video Backend Authentication

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

I am trying to understand the logic behind how AdMob works on videos. In our application we are trying to implement the feature where the user watches the entire video and earns a reward (in this case it will be some gems). I'm the developer of Android application and I've implemented the test video, it works normally. Now, here is the question:

How should we validate from the backend server that this video has been watched and closed? Can something be done on the backend server via a webhook or something? Because in the "Reward Item" object in Android there is no special token for us to communicate with the backend part, just reward type as string (which returns "Coins") and amount as integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RewardedVideoAdListener & check...

following are the events/methods in the listener -

```
@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewarded! currency: " + reward.getType() + "  amount: " + reward.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Reward the user.
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoCompleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know what the events are, though. I'm just looking for a validate string or a special token to communicate with backend. Sending "reward type" and "amount" on their own can be tracked down easily and may cause spams.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul currently not possible

Comment: Then how are the applications actually validate these watched videos? Is there another way that I don't know?

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul App's validate with the onRewardVideoCompleted() event in the listener! :)

Comment: Yeah but what message should I send to backend when it's actually completed to verify? Sending a plain request can be trackable but with a special token mechanism it can be prevented. Sending the same data without tokens will cause a spam in this case. I'm asking this because backend data should change as well, I can't only handle them in local.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul you can encrypt the boolean value & send it to server!

Answer (score 0):

first : implements RewardedVideoAdListener

```
@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
    // get reward send to backserver
    // Reward the user.
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
    // if client cancle the video call
    // send backServer
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoCompleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

on use onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() method

Comment: Thank you for your reply as well, but sending the reward data without a token is not safe, since they are pretty obvious and explicit. In the "Reward Item" object there are two methods: getType() and getAmount(). Get type returns a string such as "coins" and amount returns the value. But there is no token to actually verify a token string to prevent spamming on backend server.